# Append new column to a dataframe by reading parquet files first

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Assume there is a dataframe with multiple columns, which looks smth like this (I omitted unnecessary columns):

```
+----------------------------------------+
|path                                    |
+----------------------------------------+
|/tmp/some_folder/2020-04-02/blabla1.parq|
|/tmp/some_folder/2020-05-14/bla2bla.parq|
+----------------------------------------+
```

Where path is some parquet file in hdfs, which has only one row and a structure like this:

```
+-----------+
|value      |
+-----------+
|some value |
+-----------+
```

How can I read those files and add a column ('value') to the initial dataframe? As a result, I want a structure like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+----------+
|path                                    |value     |
+----------------------------------------+----------+
|/tmp/some_folder/2020-04-02/blabla1.parq|some value|
|/tmp/some_folder/2020-05-14/bla2bla.parq|bla blah  |
+----------------------------------------+----------+
```

For instance, I can turn the 'path' column into a list, read into datframes by iterating it and join with the initial dataframe. Are there any other solutions? Preferably faster performance-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by reading multiple parquet files at once: `spark.read.parquet(f"/tmp/some_folder/{2020-04-02/blabla1.parq, 2020-05-14/bla2bla.parq}")`
The "path" column was then added using input_file_name().

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid join by using **`input_file_name()`**  so that `path` will be added to the dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

paths=df.select("path").rdd.map(lambda x:x[0]).collect()

#schema will the fields
sch=StructType([StructField("path",StringType()),StructField("value",StringType())])
final_df=spark.createDataFrame([],schema)

for path in paths:
    final_df=spark.read.parquet(path).withColumn("path",input_file_name())

#dataframe will have path and value to it
final_df.show()
```